# Remove special character in json key name in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

I'm recieving a excel json parsed and in key name have . $, I want to remove those.(i can't change anything on excel file)

in my first moment I try to parse to string and use regex, but I can't change anything of the value.

any suggestions?

example of the code:

```
{"example1.":"sometext.","example2.":"anothertext."}
```

and a I want to cant to

```
{"example1":"sometext.","example2":"anothertext."}
```

I create a function to handle this error, if some one know better answer to that i be glad.

```
const KeyNameinJson = (json, callback) => {
let newJson = {};
let PropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(json);
let async = require('async');
async.each(PropertyNames, (key, callback) => {
    let newKey = key.replace(/[|&;$%@."<>()+,]/g, "");
    newJson[newKey] = json[key];
    callback();
}, () => {
    callback(newJson);
});
```

};

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, like i show in the code above

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need `async` for this task. Can this be achieved in a simpler way?

```js
'use strict';

const obj1 = {"example1.":"sometext.","example2.":"anothertext."};
const obj2 = {};

for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1)) {
  obj2[key.replace(/[|&;$%@."<>()+,]/g, "")] = obj1[key];
}

console.log(obj2);
```