# How to replace the $ symbol from json object key in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jenkins, async.js

I am trying to remove the $ symbol from the key in json object(parsed). Normal JS file I used [Remove special character in json key name in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887286/remove-special-character-in-json-key-name-in-nodejs) this answer mentioned and it is working fine. But I tried in nodejs due to async it is not working properly. The last formed object did not contain the entire modified value. So I tried the original function which is posted in the question but I am getting callback function not found error. I am using node 10.19 version. Is there any other way I can remove the $ symbol from my json object. Please give me a working solution. Actualy I am getting the input from yml file which gets converted to json string in jenkins. And again In my code I have parsed it. If there any library to directly convert yml file to json in jenkins that will also help.

```
var obj = {

    'blue':{
        'test:"value',
        '$test1':'value1',
        'tiger':'cheetah_growl',
        '$jan':'cool'
    }

}
```

Normal js file

```
var obj_new = { '$name': 'test1', '$auth_users': 'bajali_s' };

console.log("obj.blue",obj.blue.tiger);
var str = obj.blue.tiger;
var res = str.replace("_", " ");
console.log("res",res);

obj.blue.tiger = res;

console.log("obj.blue",obj.blue.$test1);



//const obj1 = {"example1.":"sometext.","example2.":"anothertext."};
const obj2 = {};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));

const obj1 = obj_new;
console.log("__",obj1);
/* for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1)) {
  obj2[key.replace(/[|&;$%@."<>()+,]/g, "")] = obj1[key];
} */

for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1)) {
  obj2[key.replace(/[|&;$%@."<>()+,]/g, "")] = obj1[key];
}


console.log("==",obj2); 

var newjson = JSON.stringify(obj2);

console.log(newjson);
```

Comment: Take out the irrelevant code. Also there is a syntax error in the top snippet.

Comment: Your code is quite hard to understand. Why do you have so many `obj`-variables? Could you give a small, simpler, example of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to remove the extra symbol in the key and value. I went through many sites and came up with this procedure hope it helps someone. I have also made it little dynamic.

```
 var special_char_keys = ["creationType", "vm_location", "nic_location", "vnetlocation", "rg_location"];
        var elements_to_delete = ["blueprint_info", "riglet_info", "quick_links"];


        for (var a = elements_to_delete.length; a >= 0; a--) {
            delete cloudProperties[elements_to_delete[a]];
        }

        var Mainkeys = Object.keys(cloudProperties);
        console.log("Mainkeys", Mainkeys);
        var total_keys_cloudproperties = Mainkeys.length;



        for (var j = total_keys_cloudproperties; j > 0; j--) { // main json loop starts

            for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cloudProperties)) { // getting the main json keys

                var obj1 = cloudProperties[key];
                var obj2 = {};
                var obj3 = {};
                var obj4 = {};
                var obj5 = {};
                var formattedarray = [];

                var keys = Object.keys(cloudProperties[key]);
                //console.log("inner keys", keys);
                var tasksToGo = keys.length;

                //console.log("key length",tasksToGo);
                for (var i = tasksToGo; i > 0; i--) {



                    for (const key1 of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1)) {
                        //   var item = obj1.get(key1);  // this will get the value in the json based on key

                        if (Array.isArray(obj1[key1])) { // checking whether the key has value as [{},{}]

                            // console.log("for jsonarray case");
                            var temparray = obj1[key1]; // assigning the array to temparray
                            for (var k = 0; k < temparray.length; k++) { // for loop for getting each object value
                                var obj3 = temparray[k]; // assigning the inner object to a variable
                                var Arraykeys = Object.keys(obj3);
                                // console.log("array inner keys", Arraykeys);
                                var tasksToGo1 = Arraykeys.length;

                                for (var t = tasksToGo1; t > 0; t--) {
                                    for (const key2 of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj3)) {

                                        if (special_char_keys.includes(key2)) {
                                            var tempvalue = obj3[key2];
                                            var newvalue = tempvalue.replace("_", " ");
                                            // console.log("newvalue", newvalue);
                                            obj4[key2.replace(/[|&;$%@."<>()+,]/g, "")] = newvalue;

                                        } else {
                                            obj4[key2.replace(/[|&;$%@."<>()+,]/g, "")] = obj3[key2];
                                        }
                                        // obj4[key2.replace(/[|&;$%@."<>()+,]/g, "")] = obj3[key2];


                                    }
                                    if (Arraykeys == tasksToGo1) {
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    temparray[k] = obj4;
                                    // console.log("temparray[k] ======================", temparray[k]);
                                }

                            }
                            obj5[key1] = temparray;
                            cloudProperties[key] = obj5;
                            // console.log("vm case", cloudProperties[key]);
                        } else {
                            // console.log("for normal case");
                            if (special_char_keys.includes(key1)) {
                                var tempvalue = obj1[key1];
                                //  console.log(obj1[key1]);
                                var newvalue = tempvalue.replace("_", " ");
                                // console.log("newvalue", newvalue);
                                obj2[key1.replace(/[|&;$%@."<>()+,]/g, "")] = newvalue;
                                cloudProperties[key] = obj2;


                            } else {
                                obj2[key1.replace(/[|&;$%@."<>()+,]/g, "")] = obj1[key1];
                                cloudProperties[key] = obj2;

                            }


                            //obj2[key1.replace(/[|&;$%@."<>()+,]/g, "")] = obj1[key1];
                            // cloudProperties[key] = obj2;
                        }
                    }

                }
                //console.log("obj2",obj2);

                //console.log("+++++++++++++++++",cloudProperties[key]);


            }
            if (j == total_keys_cloudproperties) {
                //console.log("inside break");
                break;
            }
        }




        console.log("After removing", cloudProperties);
```